# What would be the correct syntax to round decimal quotient values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

If I sum certain values in SQL and divide by another sum of values, I get a decimal value. I was hoping to have those values round to the closest .5 or .10, but when I run a query my quotient is 0. I'll multiply my values by 2, round, and then divide by 2.

```
ROUND((SUM(SALESTAX) / SUM(NULLIF(TOTALCOST, 0))*2),0) / 2 

RESULT
0.000000
```

If I simply Round by 2 I get I'll get rounded values, but not the correct ones.

I don't know why that would be wrong unless, I'm not really multiplying anything by how my query is written.

Comment: You know that if there will be null on the second sum, this query will fail? Change `NULLIF` to put 1, not 0.

Comment: What are the data types of SALESTAX and TOTALCOST? I think you may be running into a [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) issue.

Comment: Can you replace your columns with variables of the same type and post a script that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: they are doubles, I was thinking that could be the issue as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I am understanding your requirement correctly I believe you simply have a wrong value in your ROUND function. Seems to me that you are rounding to 0 decimal places. I think you want this...

```
ROUND((SUM(SALESTAX) / SUM(NULLIF(TOTALCOST, 0))*2), 2) / 2
```

I think you can get rid of the multiply by 2 and divide by 2 as well.

Comment: that's it. Thanks!